# How do I fix a leaking kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

I have this kitchen sprayer faucet and it has started to leak. The leak is only from the spout and the leak stops when the main handle is in off position. I already tried changing the cartridge and it doesn't work.

What should I try next?

[image]

Comment: here is a video if it helps https://imgur.com/FqMVeZi

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Good, clear, focused, well lit pictures are the greatest help. You can [edit] them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the sealing ring in side.

Comment: Inside the handle on the left faucet that is.